# How Laravel Append Two Object result to one Collection Object

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to con-cat two query result to one collection and pass to Laravel Resource file.

What I Did:

1. There is a Function called: `getDailyUsageByPeriod($dateFrom, $dateTo, $serviceId)`, This is return an array of daily usage for a given period.
2. There is a function called: `getTotalUsageByPeriod($dateFrom, $dateTo, $serviceId)`, This is return total for the given time period.

Ex- if user gave one week date range to `$dateFrom` and `$dateTo` variable first function return daily usage and second function return total usage for one week.

Then I return this result to Resource file. In the resource file

```
$dailyUsage = $this->getDailyUsageByPeriod($dateFrom, $dateTo, $resultForServiceNumber->id);
$totalUsage = $this->getTotalUsageByPeriod($dateFrom, $dateTo, $resultForServiceNumber->id);
```

`$dailyUsage->total = $totalUsage;`

How Return as a One collection object to resource file, because currently I am getting total record repeats.

```
     `{
        "date": "2019-06-01",
        "peakPeriod": {
            "upload": "496047",
            "download": "496047"
        },
        "offpeakPeriod": {
            "upload": "22233301",
            "download": "12312332"
        },
        "totalUsage": {
            "peakUpload": null,
            "peakDownload": null,
            "offpeakUpload": null,
            "offpeakDownload": null
        }
    },
    {
        "date": "2019-05-01",
        "peakPeriod": {
            "upload": "12312343",
            "download": "37044092"
        },
        "offpeakPeriod": {
            "upload": "22233301",
            "download": "12312332"
        },
        "totalUsage": {
            "peakUpload": null,
            "peakDownload": null,
            "offpeakUpload": null,
            "offpeakDownload": null
        }
    }`
```

Comment: Why not create an array then push each of these objects into the array. This makes for easier consumption subsequently.

Comment: [''daily" =>$dailyUsage, "total" => $totalUsage ] this is the array I created I get two object, what is the implementation in the resource file to get daily array and total separate object. Currently it is repeating.